# Customizing dynamically the edit_handler depending of the type of user

Tags: wagtail, modeladmin

My app have some models that can be edited with modelAdmin. Is it possible that some fieldpanels are hidden to some types of users?

I can't find in the docs how to modify dynamically the edit_handler depending of the type of user.

Answer (score 1):

You can sub-class `FieldPanel` and override the `render_as_field` and/or `render_as_object` methods. Within those methods you will have access to the request, which is bound to the model in `bind_to_instance` (see https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py#L137).

Here's an example:

```
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel


class CustomFieldPanel(FieldPanel):

    def render_as_field(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return ''
        return super().render_as_field()
```

Comment: I tried using this example and it works fine if a super user is editing the page. But if a default user is editing the page, the CustomFieldPanel content is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Make the `required_fields` method return an empty list.

```
# panels.py
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel


class PermissionFieldPanel(FieldPanel):
    def __init__(self, *args, permission: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.permission = permission

    def clone_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().clone_kwargs()
        kwargs['permission'] = self.permission
        return kwargs

    def required_fields(self):
        if self.request and self.request.user.has_perm(self.permission):
            return super().required_fields()
        return []
```

```
# models.py
from wagtail.core.models import Page

form panels import PermissionFieldPanel


class ArticlePage(Page):
    admin_notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    settings_panels = Page.settings_panels + [
         PermissionFieldPanel('admin_notes', permission='myapp__some_permission'),   
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way which I found recently (also faced with this problem).
If you don't need to hide panel but only make it read-only, you can just create let's say `NewFieldPanel` inherited from base `FieldPanel` and override `bind_to_instance` method (originally found the tip [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1680#issuecomment-409365242)).

The example of implementation:

```
class NewFieldPanel(FieldPanel):
    def bind_to_instance(self, instance=None, form=None, request=None):
        # form.fields['managers'].widget = HiddenInput()
        form.fields['managers'].disabled = True
        return super().bind_to_instance(
            instance=instance, form=form, request=request
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

... now, if it were *me,* I would probably opt to set up two entirely different panels, even though they would be maintained together and would look the same.  Because, "sooner or sooner," one view *will* diverge from the other, and this can add complexity very quickly.  Therefore, appealing though it may be to approach this problem by "selectively hiding things," you might come to wish that you hadn't done it this way.  I think it's better to have two redundant panels, with a clean implementation for each, than to have two pieces of code that become littered with `if`-statements ... but that is strictly my opinion.

Comment: I'm _pretty sure_ OP is asking how to selectively modify whether or not a FieldPanel is displayed/how a FieldPanel behaves based on some attributes of the user. In this case it doesn't make sense to create different panels, but rather one FieldPanel that responds to attributes of the logged in user (via `request.user`).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above (can't add comment to it sorry).

Instead of `render_as_field` sometimes you should use `render_as_object`. It depends.